# Get value of tbody td

Tags: javascript

I saw other questions and answers and doesn't meet my need.

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td>a2</td>
    <td>a2</td>
  </tr>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>a2</td>
    <td>a2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4d</td>
    <td>a23</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>

<script>
$('tr').on("click", function(){
    var id = $(this).find('tbody tr td').eq(2).text(); //here
    alert(id);
});
</script>
```

I want to get tbody td not thead td, and i tried above code on script.
But alert does occur with no value.(empty alert)
Hm... did I type something wrong?

Comment: you miss tab close </thead>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below script will get the value of the first `td` of the `tbody tr`

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td>a2</td>
    <td>a2</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>a2</td>
    <td>a2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4d</td>
    <td>a23</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<script>
$('tbody tr').on("click", function(){
    var id = $(this).find('td:first-child').text(); //here
    alert(id);
});
</script>
```

If you want to get the value of each `td` clicked you can use:

```
$('tbody td').on("click", function(){
    var id = $(this).text(); //here
    alert(id);
});
```

Comment: Or you can use td:last-child for last element

Answer (score 0):

`this` inside a jQuery handler will refer to the element that triggered the event - you're using `$('tr').on`, so `this` will refer to a `tr`. But `tr`s don't have `tbody` children, so `$(this).find('tbody ...` doesn't work. Instead, since you're *starting* from the `tr`, just `.find` `td`s. Also note that since you only have *two* `td`s in each `tr`, `.eq(2)` will always be empty (array-like collections are zero-indexed in Javascript) - if you want the second `td`'s text, you should use `.eq(1)` instead.

```js
$('tr').on("click", function() {
  var id = $(this).find('td').eq(1).text();
  console.log(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>a2</td>
      <td>a2</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>a2</td>
        <td>a2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4d</td>
        <td>a23</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your script is that :

```
<script>
 $('tr').on("click", function(){
 var id = $(this).find('tbody tr td').eq(2).text(); //here
 alert(id);
});
</script>
```

1) You are referring to column 2, which does not exist. 
2) Moreover, writing "find('tbody tr td')" will search for another tbody tr and td tags within the "$('tr').on("click", function()" that you are searching for, which doesn't exist either, hence alert returns blank. So try this script and let me know if it works!

```
<script>
  $('tbody tr').on("click", function(){
   var id = $(this).find('td').eq(0).text(); 
   alert(id);
  });
</script>
```

---

---